# Can't use overloaded operator<< to print object's value

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, iostream

I wrote tuple implementation, which seems to work:

```
template<typename T, typename... U>
struct tuple{
    T first;
    tuple<U...> second;
    tuple()=default;
    tuple(T t, U... u):first(t), second(u...){}
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& stream){
        stream<<first<<", ";
        return second.print(stream); //not using << to avoid extra () in output
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct tuple<T>{
    T first;
    tuple()=default;
    tuple(T t):first(t){}
    operator T&(){
        return first;
    }
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& stream){
        return stream<<first;
    }
};

template<typename... T>
inline auto mk_tuple(T... t){
    return tuple<T...>(t...);
}
```

I have `operator<<` overloaded this way:

```
template<typename... T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, tuple<T...> &out){
    stream<<'(';
    return out.print(stream)<<')';
}
```

When I try to use it this way: `std::cout<<mk_tuple(1, 2, 3, "xyz", 'c');` I get

> `error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’`

However, `mk_tuple(1, 2, 3, "xyz", 'c').print(std::cout)` works.
(but it's unsatisfactory, because it's not obvious syntax in C++).

**How should I overload `operator<<` to be able to use it correctly in this case?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature is wrong, you need:

```
template<typename... T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const tuple<T...> &out){
//                                             ^^^^^
```

since you are not going to *modify* the `tuple` on output. This then allows your operator to be called with constant or temporary values.

It also requires you to mark the `print` method as `const`:

```
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& stream) const {
//                                        ^^^^^
```

Generally, google "const correctness" and learn about this essential paradigm in C++.

---

EDIT: Got it! Try this signature:

```
template<typename T, typename... U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const tuple<T, U...> &out){
    stream<<'(';
    return out.print(stream)<<")";
}
```

as some older versions of GCC seem to have a bug that prevents them from properly deducing just `T...`s.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I can't read your mind, so you have to be more specific: After fixing the operator and **both** signatures of `print`, what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: `error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’` and `/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = tuple<int, int, int, const char*, char>]’` [My whole code in online compiler](http://rextester.com/live/YZWQ61891)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Huh. That exact code is accepted by GCC 4.9 as well as GCC 4.8 on my local system.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0876a0c9aa676719) and I can't see anything wrong with the code. Strange.

Comment: @hvd: I have g++ 4.8.2, on Rextester is g++ 4.8.1, and it doesn't work under both of them...

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I have 4.8.3. The list of bugs fixed in 4.8.3 is a bit too large to easily see if there's anything that might have an effect of making this work.